# Activate Translation in Pyramids

Tags: python, internationalization, translation, pyramid

I want to activate my translations in pyramids framework. Therefore I have added the translation directorys and set a local negotiator like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11289565/2648872 and desribed in http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/narr/i18n.html#default-locale-negotiator. Additionally the default and available language in my ini files are set, but pyramid wont accept my translations. Do i miss something for activating translations?

Greetings

Tobias

**Edit**:

Snippet of my production.ini

```
[app:main]
use = egg:dbas

pyramid.reload_templates = true
pyramid.debug_authorization = false
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
pyramid.debug_routematch = false
pyramid.default_locale_name = de

available_languages = de en
```

And out of my **init**.py:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
[...]
config = Configurator(settings=settings,root_factory='dbas.database.RootFactory') 
config.add_translation_dirs('locale') 
[...]
config.set_locale_negotiator(my_locale_negotiator)
```

Additionally the settings are logged, and default_locale_name as well as available_languages are visible. Unfortunately in my_locale_negotiator, they are not readable :(

My folder structure is like:

```
dbas
|- setup.py
|- development.ini
|- [...]
|-dbas
  |- __init__.py
  |- views.py
  |- [...]
  |- locale
    |- dbas.pot
      |- de
        |- LC_MESSAGES
        |- dbas.mo
        |- dbas.po
    |- en
      |- LC_MESSAGES
        |- dbas.mo
        |- dbas.po
```

Comment: At least add code for my_locale_negotiator. Make more clear what you are doing to switch languages, what should happen and what happens instead of expected behaviour. Add exceptions or logging if available. I got this running in pyramid 1.5. You may remember me.

Comment: My local negotiator is like the one, described in the cookbook: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/narr/i18n.html#Locale Negotiators. My expectations are a webpage, which is translated into german, because this should be the default language. Instead the translated one I got the englisch page :( And yeah, I'm remebering you and your helpful tipps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue, cause my macro-structure of chameleon templates was malicious.

Comment: I intentionally did not asked for this but had question for the templates on my list of prerequisites. There are lots of pitfalls. I would recommend having a smaller project that just tests pyramid framework features on i18n/l10n. Danilo Dellaquila did this some time ago - things have changed a bit since then (https://github.com/ddellaquila/pyramid_i18n_howto). If the concepts work in smaller (isolated) environment you can implement similar concepts in your larger application. That makes debugging much easier for you - and for guys on SO too :-)

Comment: I'll keep this in my mind. Especially as lateral entrant there are lots of pitfalls :)

Answer (score 1):

Pyramid actually does not find your translation dirs. [According to docs you need to pass absolute directory paths or asset specifications](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/api/config.html#pyramid.config.Configurator.add_translation_dirs). I prefer an asset specification, since I am used to do this for view configuration as well.

```
config.add_translation_dirs('dbas:locale')
```

You do not need a custom locale negotiator for your use case since [you are applying localization-related deployment settings](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/narr/i18n.html#localization-deployment-settings). Disable the custom locale negotiator in the pyramid configuration. [Rely on the pyramid implementation of the default locale negotiator](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/narr/i18n.html#the-default-locale-negotiator).

You just [need two things to activate translations](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/narr/i18n.html#activating-translation). Only apply these two concepts first.

For debugging purpose you can [use one these concepts to set locale manually](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/narr/i18n.html#setting-the-locale). I really liked passing a *LOCALE* value in the query string. For example, visiting

```
http://my.application?_LOCALE_=de
```

Comment: For debugging, I'm currently have this line: config.add_translation_dirs('locale', 'locale/', 'dbas:locale'), but this won't fix it.

Comment: The first two are neither absolute paths nor asset specs. This may break the iteration over the specs sequence

Comment: This has no influence on the sequence. At first I only had 'dbas:locale' and due to no translations, I added the other ones :\ Unfortunately settings[#available_languages’] is 'None', when I ask for it in my_locale_negotiator.